# PrintDocument.Print is not correctly outputting a TIFF

Tags: c#, tiff

I have a TIFF that prints fine from Microsoft Paint.  I print the same tiff from my program:

```
        string quickPrinterName = "hp4050";
        string fileName = @"C:\Development\TiffStuff\testoutputAsTiff0.TIF";
        var ex = new PrintingExample(fileName, quickPrinterName);
```

PrintingExample comes directly from the MSDN for [PrintDocument.Print](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print.aspx).  Basically all I did was replace their Main implementation with the 3 lines you see above in a console app.  Note that my program did print a `test.txt` file just fine too.

When I print using a PCL5 driver I get wingding's.  When I print with PCL6 I get

PCL XL Error

> Subsystem: Image, Error: IllegalAttributeValue, Operator: ReadImage,
>   Position: 48.

I've tried umpteen different ways to print TIFF's.  I can splitup the tiff into individual files just fine.  Just no prints...

Comment: you based your program on the example on the website? so you also changed the part where it renders text to something that renders images?

Comment: Negative.  I didn't notice that!  Thanks I'll try it again.

Comment: @olydis - That fixed it.  I was looking for something more complex.  Well, if you wanna put down the fix I will mark it.  Maybe somebody else will run into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printing example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print.aspx) is designed specifically to print text! Using `PrintDocument`, it is printed whatever you render to the `Graphics` property of the `PrintPageEventArgs` provided when `PrintPage` is fired.

In your case, instead of opening and rendering a text-file line by line, you should load the file into a `Bitmap`/`Image` object and render it using `Graphics.DrawImage` or similar. ;)